# Nonsense instantiation

Tags: c++, class, instantiation

Well, I'm just at the beginning of a `.C` file and started testing. Such short lines and I don't really get where the problem is. I created a class, which I'll name `Class` with data members `double* a` and `double* b`. I also make a constructor where I set that data members. But that does not seem to work. For some reason `a` is set with the value that should go to `b`.

So, here's my (short-short) `.h` file:

```
class myclass 
{
 public:
  myclass (double*, double*);

 private:
  //data members
  double*  a;
  double*  b;

};
```

And here's my `.C`:

```
#include "myclass.h"
#include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

myclass::myclass (double* inputa, double* inputb)
{
  cout << endl << endl <<  "Before instanciating"<< endl;
  for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    cout << "inputa[" << i << "]= " << inputa[i] << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    cout << "inputb[" << i << "]= " << inputb[i] << endl;

  cout << endl << endl << "While instanciating..." << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i<3 ;++i)
    {
      a[i] = inputa[i]; cout << "a[" << i << "]= " << a[i] << endl;
      b[i] = inputb[i]; cout << "b[" << i << "]= " << b[i] << endl;
    }

  cout << endl << endl << "New class object created!" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    cout << "a[" << i << "]= " << a[i] << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    cout << "b[" << i << "]= " << b[i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
  double a [3];
  a[0] = a[2] = 1;
  a[1] = 0;
  double b [3];
  b[0] = b[1] = 0;
  b[2] = 2;
  cout << endl << endl << "Before creating object" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    cout << "a[" << i << "]= " << a[i] << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i<3; ++i)
    cout << "b[" << i << "]= " << b[i] << endl;
  myclass* obj = new myclass (a, b);


  return 0;
}
```

When I run this piece of... code, the output is:

```
Before creating object a[0]= 1 a[1]= 0 a[2]= 1 b[0]= 0 b[1]= 0 b[2]= 2
Before instanciating inputa[0]= 1 inputa[1]= 0 inputa[2]= 1 inputb[0]= 0 inputb[1]= 0 inputb[2]= 2
While instanciating... a[0]= 1 b[0]= 0 a[1]= 0 b[1]= 0 a[2]= 1 b[2]= 2
New class object created! a[0]= 0 a[1]= 0 a[2]= 2 b[0]= 0 b[1]= 0 b[2]= 2
```

Reformatting the output to make it a bit easier to read (not exactly the output from the code; additional whitespace has been added):

```
Before creating object
    a[0]= 1
    a[1]= 0
    a[2]= 1
    b[0]= 0
    b[1]= 0
    b[2]= 2
Before instanciating
    inputa[0]= 1
    inputa[1]= 0
    inputa[2]= 1
    inputb[0]= 0
    inputb[1]= 0
    inputb[2]= 2
While instanciating...
    a[0]= 1
    b[0]= 0
    a[1]= 0
    b[1]= 0
    a[2]= 1
    b[2]= 2
New class object created!
    a[0]= 0
    a[1]= 0
    a[2]= 2
    b[0]= 0
    b[1]= 0
    b[2]= 2
```

What's happening?

Comment: Is your question about `C` or `C++`. You tagged `C++` and are talking about classes, yet are using a `.C` file?

Comment: @Cyber `.C` is traditionally accepted as a C++ extension. gcc and clang treat it that way.

Comment: You do stuff like `a[i] = ...` but `a` is just a pointer that doesn't point to any place you can write data to.

Comment: So, @juanchopanza, I just have to do something like:
 a = new double[3]?

Comment: You have to do whatever it takes for `a[i]` to be a valid place to write to. Now, saying `new double[3]` will do that, but it will create a whole bunch of new problems. See the advice given in the second part of the answer.

Comment: And... why is a set with b values, then?

Comment: I have no idea why you want to display same values set 4 times..
there are always a[3]={1,0,1} b[3]={0,0,2}, your third set display seem like different is because you change the way they display.... so actually just keep doing same thing...

Comment: @V-SHY I did not know where the problem was.. all that was me trying to get there... Now I see it's kinda useless

Comment: you are using what debugger? for me i am using the Visual studio and I have the exception at `a[i] = inputa[i];` when I tried to run your code, but when I compiled your code, there is no error...so it  is run-time error seem like.... your a[3] is in main scope but does not exist inside myclass scope, therefore you need to declare a[] in myclass scope again... just saw you have similar thing at header file, I think I know your question already, is why your header file instantiate is not valid?

Comment: @V-SHY kinda... But now I get it, like they said a and b are just pointers that does not point to anything. I have to initialize them and allocate space for them.
I've done that already and everything is working fine, but new doubts came to me... If you please check my response to Jarod42 answer

Comment: may be we can try to equal the pointer instead of equal the array like my second solution?

Comment: @Cyber: `.cpp` is probably the most common extension for C++ source files, but `.C` is not uncommon (that's upper case `.C`, as opposed to lower case `.c` for C source files). It doesn't work quite as well on case-insensitive file systems -- though many such file systems at least *preserve* the case of file names.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using raw pointers inside your class. It's advised also to use STL containers as std::array  (C++11) If you know at compile time the size of your array or std::vector if you want that your table will growth dynamically and in this case all memory management will be delegated to your stl container.

A possible implementation of your class Class may looks like this:

1- In case you know how exactly size you need for your array:

```
class myclass 
{
 public:
  explicit myclass (const std::array<double,3>& arr1, const std::array<double,3>& arr2) 
 {
  arrayOfDouble1_ = arr1;
  arrayOfDouble2_ = arr2;
 }

 private:
  //data members
  std::array<double,3> arrayOfDouble1_;
  std::array<double,3> arrayOfDouble2_;

};
```

2- In case you use std::vector<>

```
class myclass 
{
  public:
  explicit myclass (const std::vector<double>& v1, const std::vector<double>& v2) 
  {
      vectorOfDouble1_(v1);
      vectorOfDouble2_(v2);
  }

 private:
  //data members
  std::vector<double> vectorOfDouble1_
  std::vector<double> vectorOfDouble2_;

};



int main()
{
  // Array use
  std::array<double,3> arrayOfDouble1 = {1, 0, 1};
  std::array<double,3> arrayOfDouble2 = {0, 0, 2};
  myclass mC(arrayOfDouble1, arrayOfDouble2);

 // vector use
  std::vector<double> vectorOfDouble1{1, 0, 1}; //C++11 initialization
  std::vector<double> vectorOfDouble2{0, 0, 2}; //C++11 initialization
  myclass mC(vectorOfDouble1, vectorOfDouble2);    

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forget to declare `arrayOfDouble1`, .., `vectorOfDouble2`. And initialisation of vector in class is broken.

Comment: Except that initialisation in vector case is still broken (use initializer list). and typo for duplicated `arrayOfDouble1`.

Comment: it seems that I was not clear enough, I talked about `vectorOfDouble1_(v1);` in `myclass` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your member `a` and `b` are not initialized (with `new double[3]`).
And so your affectation `a[i] =` is undefined behaviour.

It would be safer/cleaner to use `double a[3];`, `std::vector<double> a;` or `std::array<double, 3> a;`

Comment: why would new operator "create a whole bunch of new problems" (like juanchopanza said...) ?

Comment: And... If I declare the member as double a[3] will it be accepted as an argument of type double* ?(I know this seems like a dumb question, but I've already come across errors like "can not convert double [3] to double* " or something like that

Comment: With manual `new []`, you have to think to `delete []` your resource, don't forget to manage copy of the resource (copy constructor/assignment). see [The rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) for more info.

Comment: Don't do that shit at all. Use a value like `std::array<double, 3> a`. And if it must be dynamically allocated/sized, use `std::vector`. Do not ever use `new[]`.

Answer (score 0):

simply change the instantiate of a and b in myclass.h to corresponding array?

```
class myclass 
{
 public:
  myclass (double*, double*);

 private:
  //you tried to assign array element value to following variable a and b 
    double  a[3];
    double  b[3];

};
```

### OR

Instead assign the array but assign the pointer value in your myclass::myclass()?

```
//remain old declaration in header file
double*  a;
double*  b;

//but in source file 
a[i] = inputa[i]; 
b[i] = inputb[i];
```

Replace with

```
a = inputa;
b = inputb;
```

Your *a* in myclass is **pointer of double type**.
Therefore you cannot equal it to an array but you can equal it to **another** pointer of double. ^^
After you equal the pointer value in same type, then it means you let both pointers point to same object.

By the way, I learn something that the new keyword in C++ always create a nonzero pointer to the object. thanks